# insert into select query from two tables into a third table that associates them

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert into a table, data from 2 other tables. The tables are:
products, categories, and the one that associates both, productcategory table.

So, it needs to get the id from categories, which is 776, and then all products from the products table whose name is like 'whatever' and then insert it like I said, in the associative table so that it will look something like this:

```
category_id  product_id
776            123
776            567
776            123
..etc
```

I came up with this query but it inserts me 0 rows.

```
INSERT INTO cp8_catalog_category_product
(category_id,
 product_id
)
       SELECT categorias.id,
              productos.product_id
       FROM categorias
            LEFT JOIN cp8_catalog_category_product ON categorias.id = cp8_catalog_category_product.category_id
            LEFT JOIN productos ON cp8_catalog_category_product.product_id = productos.product_id
       WHERE categorias.id = 776
             AND productos.name LIKE '%whatever%'
```

NOTE: in the associative table, category_is is not the Primary Key, it is an indexed column that is the foreign key of categorias.id

Note: yes, I have a category id in categorias table with id = 776 and I also have products in productos table whose name is like 'whatever'

Comment: Can you show sample data supporting the joins?

Comment: You are querying an id out of a table and putting it back in, so if you have unique indexes in a column or across several columns, that would block further inserts.

Comment: @paul. Well, I am getting the id from categorias table and I am trying to insert it into the associative table.

Comment: @a_horse.. mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are joining 2 tables using LEFT JOIN you have to expect that right side of join might give you 0 rows. In this case most likely productos has no rows where `productos.name LIKE '%whatever%'` for given category (joined via 3rd table)

In this case you simply want to get all products with name %whatever% and assign them to category_id 776. You cannot join productos to cp8_catalog_category_product with categorias and expect rows, because this is connection you want to produce and it doesn't yet exists.

```
INSERT INTO cp8_catalog_category_product
(category_id,
 product_id
)
       SELECT 776,
              productos.product_id
       FROM productos
      WHERE productos.name LIKE '%whatever%'
```

It is pretty common approach to use literals when you are producing rows for a table. Also a good idea is to focus on SELECT part first and work it to the point where you are certain this is output you need and then insert data into table. This way you can break down really complex tables into smaller parts.

Comment: @rafael. I pasted that and I got a #1048 - Column 'product_id' cannot be null

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the associative table gathers all products and lists to which category they belong, as a product can belong to many. so, one column is the category_id and then down the rows, all the products that belong to that 776 category.

Comment: I get that, but I wonder what do you want to insert to cp8_catalog_category_product? With current query you want to insert row to cp8_catalog_category_product if such row already exists - producing duplicate. I am not sure what exactly you want to insert there, but I doubt you want to produce duplicates.

Comment: The associative table must keep a record of which product belongs to which category.  That is what it is for. So I want all products whose name is LIKE whatever to be assigned category_id = 776 and that must be recorded into that associative table. It is not duplicates, category_id is NOT the primary key in the associative table but an FK column to categorias.id

Comment: I understand purpose of the table, please check answer if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Intelligent you are Rafal. Thank you. Indeed, I did not know I could take that straight path such as select 776 instead of trying to fetch it from categorias.  It worked out of the box.